# Nodemailer Email sending not working

Tags: meanjs, nodemailer

I'm trying to send an email from my application. I tried the below code. Can someone please help me where I'm wrong?

When I'm submitting my form, I'm not getting any error. But, I'm not able to get the email on the recipient side.

Thank you

```
'use strict';

var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
 // host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  service: "Gmail",
  port: 587,
  secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
  auth: {
    user: 'xyz@gmail.com',
    pass: '**********'
  }
});
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var path = require('path'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Enquire = mongoose.model('Enquire'),
errorHandler = require(path.resolve('./modules/core/server/controllers/errors.server.controller')),
_ = require('lodash');

exports.sendMail = function(req, res) {

  var data = req.body;
  rand=Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 54);
  host=req.get('host');
  console.log("send MailData :: " + data)
  var link="http://"+req.get('host')+"/verify?id="+rand;
  var mailOptions={
    from: data.contactEmail,
    to : 'abc@gmail.com',
    subject : "Please confirm your Email account",
    html : "Hello,<br> This is your test email for the Inquiry Form."
  }
  console.log(mailOptions);
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
    if(error){
      console.log(error);
      res.end("error");
    }else{
      console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
      res.end("sent");
    }
});
      res.json(data);

};
```

Comment: The gmail account you are using, is it configured to allow non secure apps?
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: Yes, It is configured to allow nonsecure apps.

Comment: Can you post what you do get in your console?

Comment: For this functionality, I'm not getting anything in console.

Comment: So that means this line console.log("send MailData :: " + data) does not gets called?

Comment: Yes, You're right. But now, I modified some other files and now code is working. The only problem is as defined below.

Here, I want to implement functionality like the mail should be sent from data.contactEmail and to be delivered to abc@gmail.com.

But, from the above code the mail is coming from the xyz@gmail.com and is getting deliver to the abc@gmail.com.

Comment: Lets be honest, it would be kinda strange if you could send an email with someone his/her email adres. In my project I have from: '"SomeName"<myEmail@gmail.com>' Still shows myEmail, but a different name.